# Django Rest Framework custom readonly field dependant on related model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

supposing a models.py like:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass

class Notification(models.Model):
    value = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class NotificationUserLink(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    notification = models.ForeignKey(Notification, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

The point behind normalizing instead of just having a user field on the Notification itself is for when I want to send the same Notification to hundreds of people I only need 1 Notification object. Suppose I also have an endpoint in views.py like below where the user can see all their notifications and only their notifications, which is achieved by filtering the queryset.

```
class NotificationViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = serializers.NotificationSerializer
    model = Notification
    lookup_field='pk'
    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        return Notification.objects.filter(notificationuserlink__user=user)
```

Now the "user" and "notification" pair on the NotificationUserLink model form a candidate key (they are unique together. currently just by business logic but I'll add the actual constraint to the db at some point).

Therefore, given a user in the request, each Notification (in the filtered queryset) will have 1 and only 1 NotificationUserLink to that User. Therefore, from the User's perspective, that notification is either active or it isn't, depending on the "active" field on the NotificationUserLink.

What I want to accomplish is to include that field ("active") in the serialization of the Notification. I.e. if the user hits this endpoint they should see notifications like:

```
[
{
    "value": "Bob commented on your post",
    "active": False
},
{...}, ...
]
etc
```

I think that to achieve this I will need to override the "list" method on the view. But I don't know how. The serializer is being passed a queryset in the list method so I'm not sure how to inject data into that.

The serializer currently just looks like so:

```
class NotificationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model=Notification
        fields=("value",)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [**`annotate`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.annotate) the status of the link like this in your queryset:

```
Notification.objects.filter(
    notificationuserlink__user=user
).annotate(
    active=F('notificationuserlink__active')
)
```

And then you can add a read-only field `active` field in your serializer:

```
class NotificationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    active = serializers.BooleanField(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Notification
        fields = ("active", "value",)
```